# Term for argument by extremes. Is it the same as straw man argument?

Tags: terminology

What is the correct term for the following logical fallacy?

**Speaker 1:** I believe that increasing X by 5% would be a good thing.

**Speaker 2:** By your logic, increasing X by 5000% would be a 1000x better. That's crazy!

Is this considered a *straw man* argument, *reductio ad absurdum* or some other term?

Comment: A variant of this argument is sometimes called the *slippery slope*. It's a bit ambivalent whether it's really a fallacy: what's good for the goose is good for the gander, right? --In other words, sometimes it's valid and sometimes it isn't. If it's a good idea to do X sometimes, why isn't a great idea to do it *all* the time? Sometimes it might be :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, Speaker 2 error is linearly extrapolating Speaker 1 argument, although most things don't scale linearly beyond some narrow range.

Comment: I should have thought of that: linear extrapolation.